# tomcat resteasy singleton

Tags: java, design-patterns, tomcat, singleton, tomcat7

I have war app that uses reasteasy to expose some services.
I want to deploy the app in tomcat7.

Inside this app I want to hold some information in a singleton and I want to initialize that singleton on app deploy.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed eventually to figure out how to do this

First I created a custom ServletContextListener which implements two methods: contextInitialized and contextDestroyed. 
When contextInitialized is called I instanciate my singleton object.
Then I register m custom listener in web.xml.