# Singleton in resteasy on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, singleton, jersey, resteasy

Calling a REST method created using the Resteasy library creates a new object instance for every single HTTP request. I would like to use something like `@Singleton` in the Jersey library. How can I do that in Resteasy on Tomcat?

Comment: Would the answer to this StackOverflow question help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483644/tomcat-resteasy-singleton

Comment: No this was different question. I just want not to instantiate the REST interface class every time it receives request. The Jersey library does this with @Singleton annotation.

Comment: What happens if you return those singleton classes when defining your application ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getSingletons() )?

Comment: I think you just gave me a clue where to look for my answer. I have never used the <code>Application</code> to define my REST application, I just use annotations and add a scanner in web.xml (both Jersey and Resteasy support this way). So this is something new to me and potentially it could solve my problem. I just need to read more about it.